# Can't access files on mapped network drive

Tags: c#

i have an issue where i cannot access to any file in a mapped folder

my drive N: is mapped to \erpu9\clients\, and i have 1.txt file that i'm try to read.

the function `File.Exists(@"N:\1.txt")` retun false, but `File.Exists(@"\\erpu9\clients\1.txt")` return true.
same thing happened in FileInfo.Exists.

when i try to run `File.ReadAllLines(@"N:\1.txt")` i got exception: Could not find a part of the path 'n:\1.txt', but `File.ReadAllLines(@"\\erpu9\clients\1.txt")` is working fine

I'm really lost here, Any suggestions?

i'm using Windows 10, VS2013 if it relevant

Comment: Is the drive mapping on the same computer and for the same user that your program is running on/under?

Comment: When you browse N: in the file explorer, can you see the file ? Can you open 1.txt in a text editor, without any permission issues  ? Are you properly escaping the backslashess, `File.Exists("N:\1.txt")` should be `File.Exists("N:\\1.txt")` or `File.Exists(@"N:\1.txt")` etc.

Comment: If you map the file when you have elevated privileges you won't see the mapping when you don't have elevated privileges, and vice-versa. Perhaps that's what's happening.

Comment: yes, i can see the file in FileExplorer, and edit it and delete. cannot find any reasonable reasons for this

Comment: Are you runnning your app as administrator? If yes, try not to run it as administrator

Comment: Drive mappings are per user. You either run this app as an administrator, or in IIS or another Windows Service - anyway, not under your current user account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run Visual studio with admin privilege, it's mean the user that run application in debug is different from the user that map `\\erpu9\clients` to `N:`.

Try to start visual studio with you current user and not with admin.

Comment: yes, this is the perfect solution